# Ability to edit image via WYSIWYG

Tags: images, tinymce, wysiwyg

In the wordpress post WYSIWYG, you can easily add images from the media library. But, once the  image is inserted into the post, it is not intuitive to edit the image's source to a different image in your media library. You have to remove the image completely, and then add another one in it's place.

So what I am asking is twofold:

1. Can the tinyMCE editor plugins (in this case wpeditimage) be overridden via functions.php or a plugin? Or can I totally override it with my own?
2. Do you agree with me that this is a usability issue in WP, or am I just smoking something?

Any feedback or suggestions highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe smoking something, but it doesn't change the fact that you are right ;) WP image management, (or should I say TinyMCE image management) is really sub par.

[ImagePro](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-pro-wordpress-image-media-management-and-resizing-done-right/)
might be a good solution for you. Not only does it help replacing images in editor but also resizes them and displays a server-generated resized version of the image. Anyway, it's nice for what it does. I personally used it on a couple of projects.

Comment: ImagePro hasn't beed updated for over 2 years.. any idea about a new plugin doing the same thing including updates ?